# How do I get WP Shortcodes that display page/post updated date and page/post title?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating an online database which will include profiles of various people and companies.

1) The page will always be named for the person/company it is about, and since their names sometimes change it would be great if I had a shortcode that inserted the current page/post title. Example: "On 15th January 1999, [page-post-title] announced their new product."

2) The entries will also be frequently updated and it would be really useful to have a shortcode that inserted the last modified date of the current page/post. Example: "This entry was last updated on [page-post-modified-date "jS m Y"]."

Is there a way to do this? I have searched high and low for plugins that do this and for answers to similar questions. So far no joy!

Answer (score 0):

add these in functions.php

```html
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
$u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
$updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
$updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
$custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated">Last updated on '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
} 
 
    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

add this to your page template where you want to display updation info

```html
$u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
echo "<p>Last modified on "; 
the_modified_time('F jS, Y'); 
echo " at "; 
the_modified_time(); 
echo "</p> "; }
```